# Python Advanced scheduler job not found in jobstore (apscheduler)

Tags: python, scheduler

Consider this small piece of code

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import time

class First():
    def __init__(self):
        self.remove_job=None
    def go(self):
        self.remove_job('test')
class Sched():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sched = Scheduler()
        self.sched.add_interval_job(    self.execute,
                        seconds=1,
                        name = 'test'
                        )
    def execute(self):
        print "i'm alive"
    def remove_job(self,job):
        self.sched.print_jobs()
        self.sched.unschedule_job(job)

def main():
    first = First()
    sched = Sched()
    first.remove_job=sched.remove_job
    sched.sched.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    first.go()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

python sched_test.py 
i'm alive
i'm alive
i'm alive
i'm alive
i'm alive
Jobstore default:
    test (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2011-12-22 01:25:36.577572)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sched_test.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "sched_test.py", line 51, in main
    first.go()
  File "sched_test.py", line 31, in go
    self.remove_job('test')
  File "sched_test.py", line 43, in remove_job
    self.sched.unschedule_job(job)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APScheduler-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 401, in unschedule_job
    raise KeyError('Job "%s" is not scheduled in any job store' % job)
KeyError: 'Job "test" is not scheduled in any job store'
```

Why am I getting this error while printing out the jobs works?
`print_jobs()` gives me the right overview though.

Can someone shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must pass the job instance (returned by add_interval_job) to unschedule_job instead of a string.
That fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This might be obvious for most of the people, but it took me a while to get it. Wanted just to share what made my code work:

```
myJobName= "Homework"

for job in self.sched.get_jobs():
    if job.name == "Homework":
        self.sched.unschedule_job(job)
        print "No more homework!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `First` class doesn't actually *have* a `sched` instance; it certainly doesn't have access to the `sched.sched` instance of the `Scheduler` that you *probably* want to manipulate.

```
class First():
    def __init__(self):
        self.remove_job=None
    def go(self):
        self.remove_job('test')
```

Perhaps you should construct the `Sched` object first, so you can pass it to the `First()` constructor, so you can make calls to it. I'll sketch out an *untested* mechanism I think would solve this:

```
class First():
    def __init__(self, sched):
        self.sched = sched
    def go(self):
        self.sched.remove_job('test')
def main():
    sched = Sched()
    first = First(sched)
    sched.sched.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    first.go()
    return 0
```

This keeps the `Sched` class alone -- perhaps a cleaner design could be found by merging `First` and `Sched` -- the fact that `First` knows the name of a job that `Sched` controls is a sign that something isn't quite right.

Maybe take a step back and explain what problem you're trying to solve? This doesn't feel like the cleanest solution, so I have to wonder if the problem you've got could be solved through a better mechanism.

Comment: "Note that your First class doesn't actually have a sched instance; it certainly doesn't have access to the sched.sched instance of the Scheduler that you probably want to manipulate."

I agree with that, but still why does "self.sched.print_jobs()" produce the right output then?

Comment: `self.sched.print_jobs()` works because `self` refers to an object of type `Sched` (the object is named `sched` in the `main()` function). `First` does not have access to the internals of your `Sched` objects.